# Как внести изменения в репозиторий, чтобы изменения отразились в последующих связанных репозиториях?

Tags: java, git, gitlab

Есть последовательное выполнение одного и того же проекта, состоящего из 10 удаленных репозиториев.

10й это полностью готовый проект, 1й начало выполнения.

В первом репозитории нужно внести fix, и чтобы этот fix отразился на все последующие 10 репозитории. 
Как это сделать?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не совсем правильно понимаете модель работы с git'ом. Зачем вам 10 одинаковых удаленных репозиториев?

Comment: Так по заданию нужно было делать. И почему они одинаковые? Было десять заданий, и они все разные, но основываются на предыдущем задании (т.е. репозитории)

Answer (score 1):

Автоматически сделать это невозможно. Сетевой репозиторий ничего не знает о своих локальных копиях.

Принимаем, что первый репозиторий сетевой. Изменения вносятся правильным путем и создается новый коммиит. В этом случае, в каждом локальном репозитории (последующие девять) необходимо получить эти изменения (`fetch`), и в зависимости от стратегии и выполненных изменений сделать или `rebase` или `merge`.

Может быть ваше задание в умении применять патчи через команду `git apply`, я бы уточнил.

Comment: т.е. поработав с двумя первыми репозиториями, эти изменения никаким образом не смогут отобразиться в следующих?
А для чего git apply применяется?

Comment: Смогут, но только в ручную и через сетевой репозиторий. "Сетевой репозиторий" - это термин, означающий репозиторий аккумулирующий все изменения. Это может быть и папка на диске. У вас не должно быть ситуации когда вы работает в двух репозиториях, но в разных папках. Может вы путаете с фиксациями (commit)?

Comment: Вообще ни разу ничего не слышал об "Сетевых репозиториях"..) У меня как раз и есть ситуация, когда и на локальной машине 10 папок, и удаленно тоже 10 репозиториев на Gitlab. 

Как же все таки достичь этого результата? Чтобы каждый по отдельности не править репозиторий

Comment: Удаленный=Сетевой. Автоматически НИКАК. Не должно быть 10 одинаковых репозиториев на Gitlab. Таких задач в жизни не бывает.

Comment: Почему одинаковых-то? Они отличаются друг от друга

Comment: Репозитории публичные? Есть возможность дать ссылку на них в вопросе? Пока я  не понимаю задачу.

Comment: да публичные. Было десять заданий, и нужно было создать 10 удаленных репозиториев для каждого задания